# If statements with multiple agruments to capture mouse location

Tags: if-statement, tkinter, mouseevent

I am completely self thought and so coding doesn’t come easy. Oh and my best days were Qbasic the 32k version (wow!)  I need help.
I am using Tkinter to create a Rubik’s cube program and I have reached a point where I want an If statement that looks at the mouse coordinators after a click (mouseDown) event and if the mouse is in a certain place it does something.
The “If statement” that I want is this:
If ( x>90  And  x<125  And  y>195   And  y<225):

But I cannot get it to work. I can get it to a point where the code is accepted, but it doesn’t actually work and the action is carried out once the first argument (x>80) is met.
Here's the only coding that I have come up with and works, but I wanted 1 line of code not 6 lines. I have to repeat this 27 times, so 27 x 6 is going to be a headache.

Across = x

Down = y

```
 if (across >80):

     if (across <125):

         if (down >195):

             if (down <225):
```

Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated
Hopefully yours
Martin (RubikMan63)

Comment: _"I want is this: If ( x>90 And x<125 And y>195 And y<225):"_ - then why don't you use exactly that?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(x>90 && x<125 && y>195 && y<225){
    //`enter code here`
}
```

I don't know which programming language you are using, but this is the typical and operator that is used in languages like C or C++. If you are using python then replace "&&" with "and".